# Use Dagger2 on Android run into VerifyError on certain devices

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, verifyerror

I have an Android application that uses Dagger2. I have a Dagger Component called `AppComponent`, an Activity called `MainActivity`. MainActivity has a injected field: `@Inject MainDataModel mModel`, and uses DaggerAppComponent.inject(mainActivity) to satisfy the field. I put the Component init code in Application.onCreate(). During runtime, I run into  `VerifyError` during Component initialization.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: com/myapp/a
   at com.myapp.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.initialize(DaggerAppComponent.java:39)
   at com.myapp.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.(DaggerAppComponent.java:29)
   at com.myapp.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.(DaggerAppComponent.java:19)
   at com.myapp.dagger.DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java:75)
   at com.myapp.dagger.ComponentHolder.init(ComponentHolder.java:15)
   at com.myapp.AppInitializer.init(AppInitializer.java:13)
   at com.myapp.app.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:341)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
   at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callApplicationOnCreate(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4699)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:171)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1447)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

After checking with the mapping file, I found out that the class causing the `VerifyError` msg is a `MainActivity_MembersInjector`, which is also generated by Dagger.

The line that causes this is `this.mainActivityMembersInjector = MainActivity_MembersInjector_MembersInjector.create(MembersInjectors.noOp(), this.mainDataModelProvider);` inside class `DaggerAppComponent`.

One thing to not is that it only happens on certain devices though, like Xiaomi 2014011. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Do you have any news about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `multiDex` enabled into your `build.gradle` configuration ?

Comment: Yes, multiDex is enabled.

Comment: Try without multiDex and let me know if you still experience this issue. Meanwhile you can have a look here, the problem is related with Dagger1 but probably it can affect also Dagger2:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773884/verifyerror-in-multidex-app-when-injecting-dependency-with-dagger